# Problem with filter/reaching XML Node context - Java

Tags: java

I have problems to filter my children Nodes.
I can reach them but if i do, i display them all at once, if i try to filter them, i reach nothing.
All i can filter/reach is the RootNode.

I am sure the problem is in the loop, so i was playing around with it.

My class:

```
for (int i = 0; i < messageNode.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = messageNode.getChildNodes().item(i);
        if (node.getNodeName().contains("Kino")) {
            rootNode = node;
            break;
        } else {
            if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                for (int j = 0; j < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); j++) {
                    Node node1 = node.getChildNodes().item(j);
                    if (node1.getNodeName().contains("Saal")) {
                        rootNode = node1;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        if (node1.hasChildNodes())
                            for (int k = 0; k < node1.getChildNodes().getLength(); k++) {
                                Node node2 = node.getChildNodes().item(k);
                                if (node2.getNodeName().contains("Filme")) {
                                    rootNode = node2;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    NodeList children = rootNode.getChildNodes();

    String fresult = "";

    String kino = "";
    String saal = "";
    String filme = "";
    String sitze = "";
    String ticket = "";
    String film = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
        Node child = children.item(i);
        short childType = child.getNodeType();
        if (childType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            String nodeName = child.getNodeName();

            if (nodeName.equals("Name"))
                kino = child.getTextContent();

            else if (nodeName.equals("Saalnummer"))
                saal = child.getTextContent();
            else if (nodeName.equals("TicketPreis")) ;
            filme = child.getTextContent();
        }
    }

    String message1 = "";
    message1 = createMessage(kino, saal, filme, 0);

    fresult = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\"<ns0:context_change xmlns:ns0=\"urn:unknownexercise.com\">" + message1 + "</context>";
    System.out.print(fresult);
}

private static String createMessage(String kino, String saal, String filme, int change) {

    String message = "";
    String bundle1 = "<Kino><Name>" + kino + "</Name>";
    String bundle2 = "<Saal><Saalnummer>" + saal + "</Saalnummer>" + "<Filme>" + filme + "</Filme>";
    // String bundle3 = "<Filme>"+filme;


    if (change == 0) {
        message = message + bundle1 + bundle2 + "</context>";

    }
    return message;
}
```

XML Structur:

```
<context>
<Kino>
    <Name>Cinemaxx</Name>
    <Saal>
        <Saalnummer>3</Saalnummer>
        <Filme>
            <SitzeBelegt>34</SitzeBelegt>
            <TicketPreis>9.90</TicketPreis>
            <Film>BMovie</Film>
        </Filme>
    </Saal>
</Kino>
```

Exptected result: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"<ns0:EON_MT_context_change xmlns:ns0="urn:unknownexercise.com"><Kino><Name>Cinemaxx</Name><Saal><Saalnummer>3</Saalnummer><Filme>filmecontent</Filme>/EON_MT_context></EON_MT_context>`

Output right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"<ns0:EON_MT_context_change xmlns:ns0="urn:unknownexercise.com"><Kino><Name>Cinemaxx</Name><Saal><Saalnummer></Saalnummer><Filme>
        3

            34
            9.90
            BMovie

    </Filme></EON_MT_context></EON_MT_context>
```

I want my output filtered, but it displays Saal and Filme at once.

Thats for help!